# rails4-autocomplete highlighting the dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

Items in dropdown don't get highlighted on key down, key up and mouse over.I am using rails4-autocomplete gem.

```
<%= form_tag '/search/index', method: 'get',id: 'search-field-top' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search", type: "search", data: {autocomplete: autocomplete_course_title_path} %>  
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<%end%>
```

While inspecting the dropdown, I see that no class `ui-state-focus` is added to the `<li>` tags on keyDown, keyUp or hover.